# Server SSL certificate verification fails

Tags: c#, security, ssl, ldap

I need to verify server's SSL certificate while connecting to the Active Directory service using LDAP+SSL. The root certificate is self-signed and we are running local CA service.

The problem is, server certificate verification fails on the client side even if the root certificate that created the server's SSL certificate is installed into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store of the local computer account. The client pc is not part of the domain.

This is a testing environment built with Server 2012 R2. Although we did everything for settings up a local CA, we are not sure whether the local CA service runs properly.

The sample code that verifies the server's certification on "LdapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate" event.

```
_connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = (ldapCon, serverCertificate) =>
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(serverCertificate);

    //bool _result = certificate2.Verify(); //This code also returns false

    X509Chain _chain = new X509Chain(true);
    _chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    _chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;

    bool _result = _chain.Build(certificate2);
    if (!_result)
       MessageBox.Show("Verify failed without exception.");

    return _result;
};
```

Comment: Check the OCSP endpoints (if they are there) on certificate presented by the server. If they are, check that they are reachable from your client.

Comment: @ zaitsman I do not anything about OCSP endpoints, how can I get and check them?

Comment: just download your certificate, double click it in windows OS and check all the URL's in any of the properties.

Comment: The problem is solved. I saw that our certificate has only two purposes in its purpose list and other certificates has many. Our technical support guy exported a new certificate with many usage purposes, and after importing this certificate to client machine's certificate store, validation succeeded.